# What is the easiest way to calculate Eulers Phi N?

Tags: math, encryption, rsa, prime-factoring, greatest-common-divisor

I got a number and I need to divide it into 2 factors so that I can put them into eulers phi function and calculate my n for RSA encryption, how do I find the two integers?
For example number: 1387: 19 • 73 so I get phi(1387)=(19-1)*(73-1)= 1296 = n

how do I get the 19 and 73 the fastest way? I dont want to use any internet calculators for it because I wont be able to use them in my exam.

Comment: Factor the number. The fact that you want to factor it in order to calculate Euler's phi function isn't very relevant. There are *numerous* factoring algorithms, ranging from naïve trial division to sophisticate number field methods. Since you seem to be talking about small numbers doable by a pocket calculator, just use trial division by successive odds (assuming that n is odd, as it almost always is with RSA).

Comment: so just divide the number with all possible small primes from beginning? what if the number is like 87654352? Also a huge number.

Comment: 87654352 is not a huge number. You can still factor it with a naive approach quite fast. A common algorithm is the number field sieve and all its variants, which is applicable for much larger numbers. There are quite a lot of other algorithms that can be applied to find prime factors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming.

Comment: well It was just an example, you talk about these algorithms but show me one that can do it. a good and easy one that I could use in an exam. sometimes through naive approach hits a number of 790~ I dont have time for this in an exam

Comment: There are quite a lot of resources on the internet and here in this tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prime-factoring

Answer (score 0):

In RSA,n=pq,in your example,p=19,q=73.Because p and q are all Prime number,so In your exam I think you can guess their value.I think because RSA's savety rely on value n can not be easily divided into two Prime number,so your teacher won't give a too large value n. For example，now teacher give me a value n=1387,you can think now last number is 7,so two number's value may ?3*?9 or ?1*?7.If is ?3*?9,so ?3 may equal 3,13,23,43,53,73,83... ?9may equal 19,29,59,79,89...,now you can use 1387 divide ?3,and search for whether there is an ?9 match(see whether  the result of 1387 divided ?3 is Prime number).It's
just my thought,good luck to you.